# How to detect autocomplete list mouseover and hide the palceholder span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `span` instead of `plaseholder`, When I mouse over on the items in  the autofill list, I want to also hide the span.placeholder at the sametime such as default placeholder.

[image]

```css
form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    form input {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        background: transparent;
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        outline: none;
        width: calc(100% - 10px);
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0px 5px;
    }

    div.inputs_div {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 22px;
        display: block;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 5px 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    span.placeholder {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 5px;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        display: block;
        font-size: 16px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

```html
   <form>
        <div class="inputs_div">
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <span class="placeholder">User Name</span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the default `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: I need this to some reason! it's a simple example. my big example not that.

Comment: When I try to use the code you provided, it does not work as shown. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Aso your posted question, and example, is lacking any sort of JavaScript or jQuery code. When I test your code, it is not working as you show in your Image. This makes it NOT a reproducible example and this means others will not be able to help. There is no reason to be rude when people are trying to assist you with your question.

Comment: I don’t see an auto fill list in your snippet.

Comment: I mean AutoComplete! you know my Q?

Comment: You can turn off the autocompletely by using the `autocomplete="off"` attribute and then add your own autocomplete box which has the previously inputted values

Comment: @Twisty the code example is completely correct I can see the autocomplete box

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input` and check if `input` is empty or not , if `yes` than remove `text` else show `text`

> Here used `display` property you can use according to preferences like `visibility` , `color: white`

> It will be direct answer if you provided the autocomplete code but you can use `input` `focus` to trigger and check if `input` is filled or not

```js
function toogleText() {
  var text = document.getElementById("placeholder1");
  var inputDemo = document.getElementById("inputDemo").value;

  if (inputDemo != "") {
    text.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "block";
  }
}

document.getElementById("inputDemo").addEventListener("input", toogleText)
```

```css
form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

form input {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}

div.inputs_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 22px;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="inputs_div">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="inputDemo" />
    <span class="placeholder" id="placeholder1">User Name</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: He wants that the text is removed when hovered on any autocomplete options your answer only works when I type in the input

Comment: Yes you are right @CodeFingers but as **OP** has not provided the sufficient code , given a solution without auto complete . One solution for auto complete can be run event listener when hovered on options and remove `text` , if selected than text remain removed